# Mount the other half of instance store volume

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a running c3.xlarge EC2 instance on AWS. As listed in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#StorageOnInstanceTypes , it should provide 2 x 40GB SSD instance store.

However, per `df -h`, only one of the 2 storage is mounted:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  3.6G  3.8G  49% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3.7G   12K  3.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           752M  236K  752M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb        40G  3.0G   35G   8% /mnt
```

The output of `lsblk` looks like

```
$ lsblk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvdb  202:16   0  40G  0 disk /mnt
xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 disk /
```

And I used the default settings to create the instance (so I didn't notice anything about "specify that I wanted both volumes attached"). How could I mount the other 40GB storage?

Comment: Did you specify on instance start that you wanted both volumes attached? What is the output of `lsblk`?

Comment: @EEAA Attached the output of `lsblk`; I didn't specify anything special when I started the instance through web console.